# Find date name in datetime column with user input as weekday name as a 'String'

Tags: python, pandas

I have a datetime column called 'Start Time'

[image]

I am trying to find entries with a specific weekday name based on user input.

The user input is a String and can be 
Sunday, Monday,...Saturday.  So if Sunday is input I want to find all entries that have Sunday as the day, regardless of the month or year.

Here is my code:

```
user_day = input('Input the name of the day.user_day.')

print(df[df['Start Time'].dt.weekday == dt.datetime.strptime(user_day, '%A')])
```

The output is:
    Empty DataFrame
    Columns: [Unnamed: 0, Start Time, End Time, Trip Duration, Start Station,      End Station, User Type]
Index: []

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`weekday_name`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.weekday_name.html) or [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) with same format:

```
print(df[df['Start Time'].dt.weekday_name == user_day])
```

Or:

```
print(df[df['Start Time'].dt.strftime('%A') == user_day])
```

**Verify**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Start Time':pd.date_range('2015-01-01 15:02:45', periods=10)})
print (df)
           Start Time
0 2015-01-01 15:02:45
1 2015-01-02 15:02:45
2 2015-01-03 15:02:45
3 2015-01-04 15:02:45
4 2015-01-05 15:02:45
5 2015-01-06 15:02:45
6 2015-01-07 15:02:45
7 2015-01-08 15:02:45
8 2015-01-09 15:02:45
9 2015-01-10 15:02:45

user_day = 'Monday'
print(df[df['Start Time'].dt.weekday_name == user_day])
           Start Time
4 2015-01-05 15:02:45
```

---

```
print (df['Start Time'].dt.weekday_name)
0     Thursday
1       Friday
2     Saturday
3       Sunday
4       Monday
5      Tuesday
6    Wednesday
7     Thursday
8       Friday
9     Saturday
Name: Start Time, dtype: object

print (df['Start Time'].dt.strftime('%A'))
0     Thursday
1       Friday
2     Saturday
3       Sunday
4       Monday
5      Tuesday
6    Wednesday
7     Thursday
8       Friday
9     Saturday
Name: Start Time, dtype: object
```

Comment: I tried both of these solutions and it returned an empty output, same as I received before.

Comment: @sadAndClueless72 - i think `dt.datetime.strptime(user_day, '%A')` is not necessary if compare name of day. Check edited answer.

Comment: I compared with the name of day as you suggested, print(df[df['Start Time'].dt.weekday_name == user_day]) and that worked! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

- `pandas.Series.dt.weekday`: The day of the week with Monday=0,
  Sunday=6
- `pandas.Series.dt.weekday_name`: The name of day in a week (e.g.,: Friday)

Pay attention to user input. You are loading a `string`, you don't need to convert such a string to `datetime` using `strptime`.

You just need to match the `weekday_name` of the `datetimelike` in your DF with user input. It's a string matching.

```
print(df[df['Start Time'].dt.weekday_name == user_day])
```

Comment: I got: ValueError: time data 'Sunday' does not match format '%w'

Comment: Ahhhh ok, it's due to the user input. It's a string, of course. Just edited my answer.